# Can Lucene attach (or at least track) an arbitrary Object to a Document?

Tags: java, lucene

I am following closely to a [Lucene Tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) with Lucene 3.6.

I am able to create and perform searches on `Document` objects, but I would like to get back the original objects I used to create the `Document`s. Unfortunately, Lucene seems to be serialising/deserialising the `Document`s, so I have not been able to create a lookup map between them.

**How do I keep a relationship between Lucene's `Document`s and my `Object`s? Is there a preferred Lucene way of doing this?**

*I should note that the tutorial didn't work out of the box for me, I had to add a call to `IndexWriter.commit()` after creating/attaching the `Document`s and I also have to make calls to `IndexWriterConfig.setMaxBufferedDocs()` and `IndexWriterConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB()` with big numbers to stop Lucene looking on the hard drive.*

Comment: You need to somehow uniquely mark your searchable objects, e.g. by an id, and later refer to that id. Just save the id as non-indexed in your `Document`s.

Comment: would a `Field` be appropriate for that?

Comment: Yes. In one of my applications I have an id field which I add as `doc.add(new Field("id", object.getId().toString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));`

Comment: I actually went for `Field.Index.NO` ;-) Do you want to upgrade your comment to a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a unique reference to the original object. If your objects are rows in a database, you might go with the primary key, let's assume, it is a unique `ID`.

Secondly, when creating the searchable `Document`s, just add a field like

```
doc.add(new Field("id", object.getId().toString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

You can later retrieve this field from the found documents and retrieve the original document (database entry) based on the id.

If you may have different document types, e.g. database entries and PDFs, just save the document type in the same manner, allowing you to handle the different types differently.